# How to count comma separated values retrieved from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My Sql Table Like this.
Retrieve data from table and Count Particular data from this values.If given no is 6 means the count is 4.

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+
|      id |         Values            |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
|      11 |    1,2,4,5,6              |
|      12 |    1,2,6                  |
|      13 |    4,5,6                  |
|      14 |    2,3,6                  |
+---------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: CSV in a column is not the same as array. In the long run you may regret such schema design.

Comment: you can count using php `count(explode(',', $values))`

Comment: But how to get count for a particular value

Comment: what does it mean ........If given no is 6 means the count is 4.

Comment: It means 6 is there 4 times, in the values of all the 4 rows. For ex. if given number is 2, the answer will be 3, as the given number 2 is in three rows, and not in the 13th id row. @AnkitAgrawal

Comment: As the table you shown in the question, you don't have numbers repeating in same row. Is this scenario possible for you because if it is then the answer of @M Khalid Junaid won't be correct solution as it will count a number just once in a row.  For ex. - `1,1,2,2,3` if the given number is 1 or 2 or 3, the answer will be same for all of three cases which would be 1.

Comment: In My case the numbers won't repeat in a row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find_in_set` to search the value from comma separated string

```
select count(*) total
from demo 
where find_in_set(6, `Values`) > 0;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bd3d/1)

Comment: You don't really need the `> 0` on `find_in_set` as if it fails it will return `0` or `NULL`, both of which evaluate to `false` and if it succeeds it will return a positive number which will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: It Works. Thanks M Khalid Junaid.